# setting up git server on centos 7 in google compute engine

Tags: git, ssh, google-compute-engine

I have a google compute engine instance on which I want to setup a git server which will be accessed by developers to push and pull development source code. 
I have created a user called `git` for accessing the repository. Then added every developers public key to the server `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Below are the configurations I issued to do the above mentioned

```
$ useradd –m /home/git –s /usr/bin/git-shell git
```

Install git on the server

```
$ yum install git -y
```

Configuring ssh authorization for the users

```
$ cd /home/git
$ mkdir .ssh && chmod 700 .ssh
$ touch .ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Append developers ssh keys to the authorized_keys file on the server

Create a bare repository for the code

```
$ mkdir /opt/git/project.git
$ cd /opt/git/project.git
$ git init - -bare - -shared=group
```

Edit the existing permissions

```
$ chgrp -R developers .
```

Testing the configurations

```
$ git clone ssh://git@IP_ADDRESS/opt/git/project.git
```

when i try to clone the repository, it issues an error:

[image: git clone screen shot]

Note: I tried the above setup on a physical server and it worked perfectly and didn't need to configure ssh keys on the system. So I am wondering whether it compute engine the problem.

At some point I thought it was an issue of permission on the /opt directory, I thus modified the permissions to `read/write` for others, but it didn't work.
Also I further created a repository but in the home dir of the user git, still it didn't work.

I need some help to solve this issue of authentication of user git.

**Solution**

i found the trick behind. Actually the machine i was using to clone the project was running windows 8 OS. So the trick was to copy the `id_rsa.*` (pub and ppk) files in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh` to the git directory at `C:\Users\USERNAME\git\.ssh`.

With this everything works perfectly.

Comment: In your DOS session, do you have HOME defined? git would look for your public/private ssh key in `%HOME%\.ssh`.

Comment: you should try to `ssh -vvv git@IP_ADDRESS` to see where is the problem. Depending on the phase of fail, you shuold check server error log if it gives you more information

Comment: @VonC yes i do have, well i generated a key and copied the public key content of my dos session into the `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the git server.

Comment: @Jakuje from the post above, you can notice that the git user does not have OS console enabled but git only as per `–s /usr/bin/git-shell`

Comment: So, if you do a `dir %HOME%\.ssh`, you do see your id_rsa(.pub) in that folder?

Comment: @verane You don't have it either for github, but git is working over `ssh` and testing it with pure ssh in debug mode will help you understand where is actually the problem. As you see, it is not possible to find out from the whole long post you wrote so far.

Comment: the problem was solved by copying the `id_rsa.*` (pub and ppk) files in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh` to the git directory at `C:\Users\USERNAME\git\.ssh`. i tested this same solution on 2 different machines.

Answer (score 1):

i found the trick behind. Actually the machine i was using to clone the project was running windows 8 OS. So the trick was to copy the `id_rsa.*` (pub and ppk) files in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh` to the git directory at `C:\Users\USERNAME\git\.ssh`.

With this everything works perfectly.